# I am trying to connect my java application to hostinger.in(but no output)

Tags: java

I am trying to connect my java application to hostinger.in

I tried this code but no output is displayed.Is this code correct

```
enter code here


  Class.forName(\"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\");
  conn =                            DriverManager.getConnection(\"jdbc:mysql://mysql.hostinger.in/u869878874_stock\"       ,\"u869878874_stock\", \"bhavin\");

   stmt = conn.prepareStatement(\"SELECT * FROM logintbl\");

     ResultSet rs=null;
     rs=stmt.executeQuery();


         while (rs.next())
         { 
          usr =usr+rs.getString(\"userid\");
         }
        jLabel1.setText(usr);

         I tried this code but no output is displayed
```

Is this code correct

Answer (score 0):

Stop using escape sequence in your code and start using string directly.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html
Ex. 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

Changes to your code.

```
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement pStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM logintbl";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<database_name>", "<user id>", "<password>");
        pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL);
        resultSet = pStatement.executeQuery();
        for(;resultSet.next();){
            System.out.println("User Id " + resultSet.getString("userid"));
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: The code you posted will give compilation issues due to escape sequence. Please post the complete code which you are executing.